# How to solve Django app name conflict with external library

Tags: python, django

I made a big mistake by creating an app inside my `Django` project called `requests` that happened a long time ago and the system has already been running for years. now I need to use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library and it is being imported like  `import requests` as mentioned in the documentation ... and of course whenever I do this import it imports my app instead of the library .. so how to solve this?
[image]

Comment: The requests library has nothing to do with django

Comment: @mousetail you mean I can do HTTP requests using another library? I don't understand your comment !!

Comment: Not directly related to your question. The `requests` library is unrelated to django. It can be used separately and there are many other similar libraries that can be used in django.

Comment: Does your Django app have models? If so, what database are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try importing the `requests/__init__.py` file directly as shown in docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly.

Example:

```py
import sys
import importlib.util

module_name = 'requests'

# declare the full path to requests/__init__.py file below
module_path = '/path/to/virtualenv/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
requests = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = requests
spec.loader.exec_module(requests)

print(requests.post) # should not raise error
```